# Making a sidebar for Wikipedia

Tags: css, sidebar, wikipedia

I'm attempting to style Wikipedia.  I'd like to place the table of contents in a sidebar; however, I've come up against a few obstacles.  I'd like to:

- Vertically center the table of contents if it's shorter than the
  viewport height.
- Remove the scrollbar on long tables of contents while retaining scrolling ability.
- Specify a sidebar %width and min/max widths, and have the body content fill the rest.

Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kroXk.jpg) for a visual.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@-moz-document domain(wikipedia.org) {

#mw-navigation, #toctitle, #footer {display:none;}

/* Place table of contents in a sidebar */
#toc {
    height: 100%;

    width: 20%;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 250px;

    position: fixed; /* don't scroll with page. */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    overflow: hidden; /* hide scrollbar, but... */
    }

    #toc > ul {
        background: lightblue;

        overflow: scroll; /* ...still allow scrolling? */

        /* center vertically if shorter than height of viewport */
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

#content {
    /* How to have contents fill the remaining width? */
}
}
```

Does anyone have solutions to these?  Are they even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I created a userscript which allows me to define custom links that display both horizontally across the top of Wikipedia as well as in the navigation panel which sits along the left side of the page.  I copied it over to Gist in case anyone is interested.  It should help you accomplish what your looking for I think:

[Wikipedia User Defined Navigation Links (Gist)](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/f4d348519f198184fb0e)

To use this code you need to find your Wikipedia theme JS file which is going to be a subpage to your userpage.  Mine is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:David_Condrey/common.js).  You can find yours by clicking this link which will automatically direct you to the appropriate location.  You should be logged into Wikipedia first, and then [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MyPage/common.js).